# Why am I unable to mount my USB drive (unknown partition table)?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I'm a real newbie to linux. Anyway the problem is that my USB doesn't get recognized anymore which is really annoying because I need information from it. I've read like a zillion threads how to manually mount it but I really can't it to work. I hope it's just some easy, stupid problem where any of you could help me out quickly..

Here is the syslog:

```
kernel: [ 6872.420125] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2"
kernel: [ 6872.556295] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 11 was not an MTP device
kernel: [ 6873.558081] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer           8.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
kernel: [ 6873.559964] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
kernel: [ 6873.562833] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 15682559 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47 GiB)
kernel: [ 6873.564867] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
kernel: [ 6873.564878] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08
kernel: [ 6873.565485] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
kernel: [ 6873.565495] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [ 6873.568377] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
kernel: [ 6873.568387] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [ 6873.574330]  sdc: unknown partition table
kernel: [ 6873.576853] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
kernel: [ 6873.576863] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [ 6873.576871] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your system does not recongize the parition.  Are you sure the device even works and have you formated it in a way that Linux will support?

Answer (score 4):

Well, from the log it could be that the partition table of the USB device is messed up.

```
apt-get install -y testdisk
testdisk /dev/sdc
```

and try following the on-screen pointers for scanning and recreating the partition table.

This might help if the problem is not as severe as being hardware related already.